# Connecting APN using AT Commands

Tags: at-command, apn

I need to connect in internet with a usb 3g dongle using at commands.

My apn provider is:

```
APN = tim.br
Username = tim
Password = tim
```

How can I connect using only at commands? It's possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","tim.br"
ATD*99***1#
```

Comment: +1 What a blast from the past. I can't even remember AT commands anymore (except for `ATD` (or `ATDT`). I once had a 300 baud modem (thought I was cool) that only did pulse dialing (`ATDP`).

Comment: I try this, it responds "Ok" and "Connected", what I need to execute now? Or only this commands I establish a connection?

Comment: I check in OS using ifconfig (Linux) but can't get IP address. Do you know if I need to run new command to release a IP?

Comment: What happens to username and passsword?

Answer (score 4):

To connect, you need to use AT commands:

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","tim.br"
```

to configure APN, and then

```
ATD*99***1#
```

to actually connect. This will open a PPP session, and the username and password is usually provided over PAP in the PPP session itself, so you'll need to put them in your PPP client.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to connect to internet using 3G modem are the following, assuming you will use a serial command which includes two programs: 'chat' for send AT commands to the modem; 'pppd' for managing the data connection and configure a interface that you can use for the IP packet communication.

STEPS:

1. Put the USB device on modem mode, it is archieved with usb_modswitch, generally its automatic at USB plugging.
2. Configure the AT comands using a chat script:

```
# cat /var/usb3g.chat
ABORT 'NO DIAL TONE'
ABORT 'NO ANSWER'
ABORT 'NO CARRIER'
ABORT DELAYED
ABORT 'COMMAND NOT SUPPORT'

SAY 'ola'
'' ''
'' 'ATZ'
SAY 'set APN...\n'
'OK' 'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","timbrasil.br"'

SAY 'dialing...\n\n'
'OK' 'ATD*99***1#'
#'OK' 'ATD*99#' # for 2G dialling
'CONNECT' ''
```

3. Configure pppd to use the chat and negotiate the connection parameters:

```
# cat pppd.conf
hide-password
persist
nodetach
lcp-echo-interval 20
lcp-echo-failure 3
holdoff 2
connect-delay 100
noauth
/dev/ttyUSB0
115200
debug
defaultroute
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
usepeerdns
crtscts
lock
noccp
noipdefault
user tim
password tim
mtu 1490
mru 1490

# disable compression if not getting IP
#novj

connect 'chat -v -t10 -f /var/usb3g.chat'
```

If you see valid IPs on the output when calling `pppd file pppd.conf`, in an network interface called `ppp0`, all should be working well.

The above configuration I just tested for TIM Brazil, using a E3131 3G modem, and all worked fine.